# Add multiple entries for sequential items postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I want to add multiple entries, with 1 column staying the same, and 1 column increasing by 1 every time.
To do this manually I would have to do

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('1'::integer, '1'::integer)returning column1, column2;
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('1'::integer, '2'::integer)returning column1, column2;
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('1'::integer, '3'::integer)returning column1, column2;
```

etc

Is there a way I could do the numbers 1 to 34000 in 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) 
    SELECT 1, gs.n
    FROM generate_series(1, 34000) gs(n);
```

Note:  There is no need to convert a string to an integer.  In general, a number literal is fine.  In any case, Postgres would convert the number literal to the correct type if needed (say `int` or `numeric` or `float` or whatever).